# How does built-in metadata search engine in QGIS work?

Tags: qgis, metadata, search

Can somebody explain how the built-in metadata search engine in QGIS 3.36 works?

I can see "Layer metadata search" in search box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>), but can't figure out which context it has. It ignores all metadata set for layers in the current project, but can find some metadata records stored in random GeoPackages on my PC, and I can add them to the project in one click.

How could QGIS know about these GeoPackages in different locations - were they edited in QGIS on this PC before, so he remembered them?

Is it possible to find metadata stored in QGIS projects files or *.qmd* files with this mechanism?